# ABCjs compound time signature numerator not centered properly

Tags: bug, abcjs

When attempting a compound time signature, like <sup>3+2</sup>/<sub>4</sub>, the SE implementation does not properly center the numerator.

For example, the code

```
X:0
K:none
M:3+2/4
L:1/8
c6 c2 | [M:3+2+3/8] c3 c2 c3 |
```

Displays this on SE:

```
X:0
K:none
M:3+2/4
L:1/8
c6 c2 | [M:3+2+3/8] c3 c2 c3 |
```

But should display this (from https://www.abcjs.net/abcjs-editor.html)

[image: ABCjs compound meter example]

Note that the problem holds regardless whether the numerator includes the optional parentheses or not. `3+2` and `(3+2)` yield the same result.

Comment: That is quite interesting - I have had a quick play to find a workaround, and I can't quite get it right.

This definitely looks like SE's implementation - I can replicate your findings. On abcjs editor it works, and here it doesn't.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem Is there anything further I should do to request a fix?

Comment: Hi @Aaron - SE have visibility of all posts here, and ones tagged "bug" go into their backlog. I don't know how high the priority will be though, so I guess we just need to wait.